# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. (arcpy.ListFeatureClasses)

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

I am trying to change any unknown projection shape file into 
 "NAD 1983 Alaska Albers" projection.

```
# import arcypy and from arcpy, import os to change directory
import arcpy
from arcpy import os

# set working directory to workspace 
os.chdir('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase')

# Copy all dataset in working directory ###Need to change this back into my s drive
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/lab03_data/2004  _af.shp','C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/2004_af.shp')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/lab03_data/2004perimeters.shp','C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/2004perimeters.shp')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/lab03_data/AK_tundra.shp','C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/AK_tundra.shp')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/lab03_data/AK_taiga.shp','C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/AK_taiga.shp')

# find what projection 2004_af.shp, 2004perimets.shp, AK_tundra, and AK_taiga.shp
# change the projections to the correct one (2004_af.shp)

# 2004_af.shp
desc_af =      arcpy.Describe('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/2004_af.shp')
sr_af = desc_af.spatialReference
print "projection name: "+sr_af.PCSname


# 2004perimeters.shp
desc_perimeters =    arcpy.Describe('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/2004perimeters.shp')
sr_perimeters = desc_perimeters.spatialReference
print "projection name: "+sr_perimeters.PCSname

# AK_tundra.shp
desc_tundra = arcpy.Describe('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/AK_tundra.shp')
sr_tundra = desc_tundra.spatialReference
print "projection name: "+sr_tundra.PCSname

# AK_taiga.shp
desc_taiga = arcpy.Describe('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase/AK_taiga.shp')
sr_taiga = desc_taiga.spatialReference
print "projection name: "+sr_taiga.PCSname


# Here is where I got an error: arcpy.ListFeatureClasses

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('2004perimeters', 'AK_tundra', 'AK_taiga'):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
    if desc.spatialReference.PCSname == "Unknown":
        outfc = os.path.join('C://Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase', infc) 
        # Set output coordinate system
        outcs = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 Alaska Albers')
        # run project tool
        arcpy.Project_management(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(infc, outfc, outcs))
        # check messages
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` provides a list of all the feature classes in the current workspace (which you can get or set using arcpy.env.workspace). It doesn't require any arguments unless you want to filter the results with a wildcard, a feature type, or a particular geodatabase feature dataset. If you refer to the [help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001n000000), you will see that the arguments you are passing to `ListFeatureClasses` don't align with it's parameters. That's why it's returning `None`, and your `for` statement can't iterate over `None`. If you don't need to do any filtering, this will work:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase'
for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
```

If you just want to iterate over three particular datasets, then just set them explicitly (you can still use the workspace environment to save yourself from typing the full path names):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/Spring/Geog376/Lab03/erase'
for infc in ['2004perimeters', 'AK_tundra', 'AK_taiga']:
```

The ListFeatureClasses function also doesn't belong in the call to Project. Furthermore, it doesn't seem that the Project tool is what you need for this anyway. The Project tool projects data from one coordinate system to another. Instead, have a look at the [Define Projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000) tool.